# PHP, passing each element in array into function without knowing how many elements in arrray?

Tags: php, arrays, function

This is stumping me.. I am writing components / library functions where it would be used for calling a lot of different functions, so I want it to make an array print out each variable to be passed into the function as an argument, like below but I am pretty sure that this isn't proper syntax.. thanks for any advice

```
$myfunction = function_name;
$myfunction (print_r($my_array));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a built-in php function, reference from [call-user-func-array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Bang Dao's answer:

If you need to get all function arguments as array, use func_get_args().